# Adding a dotted line between two categorical points in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I've scripted the interaction plot below, for which I want two dotted lines connecting both `"coral"` and both `"darkgoldenrod2"` points respectively:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(~Proportion, ~Lower,~Upper, ~Area,~Time,
                      invlogit(-0.033886), invlogit(-0.517223067), invlogit(0.449451067), "SNP", "Day",
                      (invlogit(-0.9231219)+invlogit(-0.3786)), 0.5727 ,0.8087, "SNP", "Night",
                      invlogit(-0.9231219), invlogit(-1.406458967), invlogit(-0.439784833),"LGCA", "Day",
                      invlogit(-0.1604356), invlogit(-0.643772667) ,invlogit(0.322901467), "LGCA","Night")
df


dfnew <- df %>% 
  mutate(ymin = Proportion - Lower,
         ymax = Proportion + Upper)

p <-   ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Time, y = Proportion, color=Area)) +

  geom_point(size = 6, stroke = 0, shape = 16, 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.1))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(y=Proportion, ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper),width=0.1,size=1,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
        axis.title=element_text(size=20)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("SNP" = "coral", 
                                "LGCA" = "darkgoldenrod2"))
p
```

Reading other posts here on SO, I've used the command line: `+geom_line(aes(group = 1),size=2)`

This however isn't producing the desired plot as you can see below: [image: this]

Any help with this is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `group=Area` to your `ggplot` mapping and then you just need to call `geom_line`. You also don't need `y=Position` in `geom_errorbar`.

```
p <- ggplot(data = dfnew, aes(x = Time, y = Proportion, color=Area, group=Area)) +
    geom_point(size = 6, stroke = 0, shape = 16, 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0.1))+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper), width=0.1, size=1,
                  position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) + 
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15),
          axis.title=element_text(size=20)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("SNP" = "coral", 
                                  "LGCA" = "darkgoldenrod2")) +
    geom_line(size=2)
p
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is it possible for this line to be dotted or that is a different function?

Comment: Sure, just use `geom_line(size=2, linetype="dotted")`.